# Timeout Error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

> Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 2 for page (1:42109888), database ID 8.

I got an error when I am trying to rebuild an index using SQL below:

```
ALTER INDEX [IndexName] ON [dbo].[TableName] REBUILD
```

Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: do it after hours... rebuilding an index will take hours

Comment: I vtc to get this moved to dba.stackexchange, as you'll probably get an answer more easily there.

Comment: Can you run DBCC CHECKDB; and then ran the ALTER index script for all indexes in table: ALTER INDEX ALL ON mySchema.myTable REBUILD

Comment: why are you rebuilding an index? Do you have Enterprise licence of SQL server?

Comment: Is your database configured to use Snapshot Isolation?

Answer (score 0):

As with another recommendations try to do it after hours, what's the size of the tables/indexes?

If you have Enterprise edition you should do it online, also use parallelism (depending on your number of CPUs to make it faster)

```
ALTER INDEX [IndexName] ON [dbo].[TableName] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE=ON, MAXDOP=X)
```

Also if your tempdb is on a separate drive, you may also include sort_in_tempdb to allow the intermediate sorts be performed in tempdb which may also be beneficial.